# How to default Macros to run from This Workbook, NOT All Open Workbooks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

We have a macro enabled workbook (ver. 2010) that many people use.  A few of these people have macros in their Personal.xlsb workbook. We have a situation where the macro in the shared workbook is named the same as a macro in personal workbooks but does slightly different things.

To avoid running the wrong macro, I'd like to default the shared workbook to run macros from This Workbook instead of All Open Workbooks. I expect to place something in `WorkBook_Open()`, but what?

Is there a way to change the default option for Macros in: `All Open Workbooks` to `This Workbook`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I rename the modules that hold the subroutines, I can specify exactly which sub to call.

Example:

In Modlue1, renamed to LocalModule1, I have:

```
Sub TestDupe()
    Call LocalModule1.DuplicateName
End Sub

Public Sub DuplicateName()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    MsgBox ("new mod 1")
End Sub
```

In Module2, renamed to be LocalModule2, I have

```
Public Sub DuplicateName()
      ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      MsgBox ("mod 2")
End Sub
```

By changing the qualifier in the call from `LocalModule1` to `LocalModule2`, I can now dictate which same-named subroutine to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Can you guys just rename the macro in the shared workbook and replace the instances of that macro in that specific workbook?

Comment: We could but that doesn't prevent this from happening again.